# Userid already exists when trying to create posts with a single user (TYPEORM)

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have two entities in my application, a user and a post. In my Post entity I have the "user" column that receives the user id as a parameter through OneToOne

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, JoinColumn, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity('posts')
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @OneToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    desc: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ 
        type: 'timestamp', 
        precision: 3
      })
      createdAt: Date;    
}
```

I created the post creation controller, and it worked perfectly, but the problem is that I can only make one post for each user, if I try to create another post with the same user id that has already created a post before, it returns me the error:

```
    "detail": "Key (\"userId\")=(ffbe9e3d-13e5-4bec-b69d-990992327649) already exists.",
```

ffbe9e3d-13e5-4bec-b69d-990992327649 is the user id

controller

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { Post } from "../../entities/Post";
import { AppDataSource } from "../../database/config";

class CreatePostController {
    async store(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const { user, title, desc } = req.body;
        const post = new Post();
        
        try {
            post.user = user;
            post.title = title;
            post.desc = desc;

            await AppDataSource.manager.save(post);

            return res.status(200).json(post);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }

    }
}

export default new CreatePostController();
```

How can I make my application accept multiple posts from the same user id?

Comment: Why do users and posts are in one-to-one relation? Can each user create only one post?

Comment: I want each user to be able to create multiple posts. Would OneToOne be wrong?

Comment: Yes, you should use one-to-many or many-to-one